# How to call 2 function in XTemplate -Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to call the function `renderFunction` in XTemplate in extjs  but it is not calling `renderPartition`. Is this the right way to call the function in extjs?

Not able to see any console error.

```
Igo.EndpointTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tr>',
        ' <th class="header-140">Media Handler</th>',
        ' <td>{endpointInstance.mhaddress}{[this.renderPopName(values.endpointInstance.mhaddress)]},{[this.renderPartition(partitionValue)]}</td>',
        '</tr>' {


            renderPopName: function(address) {
                if (address) {
                    var popId = address.split(".", 2)[1];
                    return Ext.String.format('<span class="txt-color-red"> ({0})<span>', Igo.Pop.getFriendlyName(popId));
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },

            renderPartition: function(records) {
                let get_internalId = records[0].internalId;
                let ele_meetingID = records[0].data.meetingID;
                let ele_Partition = records[0].data.partition;
                if (ele_Partition && ele_meetingID === get_internalId) {
                    return Ext.String.format('<span class="txt-color-red"> ,({0})<span>', ele_Partition);
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Can you show runnable code in sencha fiddle

Comment: @tejas this completely huge code, minimal code i have shown here

Comment: I can show completely demo on this via other means

Comment: Yes you can call multiple function in xtemplate. check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2ot6)

Comment: Perhaps it have to do with partitionValue been a record and not a simple value

Comment: @JMR remember one thing more when you passing value in function from xTemplate it will be object not a record. don't access like this `record.data.xxx`

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Records is argument passed...Thanks for you info as well

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of typos in your snippet, a missing comma after last tr tag, a closing braces is missing. Also I would suggest using array notation for your xtemplate. Here is your snippet with my suggested changes. Template functions were firing in my example

```
Igo.EndpointTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(['<tr>',
' <th class="header-140">Media Handler</th>',
' <td>{endpointInstance.mhaddress}{[this.renderPopName(values.endpointInstance.mhaddress)]},{[this.renderPartition(partitionValue)]}</td>',
'</tr>',{
    renderPopName : function(address) {
        if (address) {
            var popId = address.split(".", 2)[1];
            return Ext.String.format('<span class="txt-color-red"> ({0})<span>', Igo.Pop.getFriendlyName(popId));
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },

    renderPartition: function(records){
        let get_internalId = records[0].internalId;
        let ele_meetingID = records[0].data.meetingID;
        let ele_Partition = records[0].data.partition;
        if(ele_Partition && ele_meetingID === get_internalId){
            return Ext.String.format('<span class="txt-color-red"> ,({0})<span>', ele_Partition);
        }else{
            return "";
         }
    }}
  ]);
```

Comment: this not the problem. Just remove the comma and try to run you will get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. And OP is already mention in question that means he not getting this type error

Comment: pardon me if I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: If you providing any suggestion or correction you need to put comment instead of providing answer.

Comment: I thought it was the correct answer at the time of writing it, if you like, I can delete my answer, not sure what the etiquette is in this case